# Unable to Clear the Timout on Speed Reader app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a small speed reader app just just for fun :) inspired by Spritz.

Can anyone figure out how to stop this from running using the speedr_stop(); function?

Here's the html:

```
<div class="speedr-wrapper">
<input class="speedr-button" type="button"value="click me" onclick="speedr_init(200)" />
<div class="speedr"></div>
</div>
<div class="readable">
<p>This paragraph should be read in the speedr div.</p>
```

... and the javascript (uses jquery)

```
function speedr_init(speed) {

    //toggle the button - currently can't get it to stop :(
    $('.speedr-button').attr('onclick', "speedr_stop()");
    $('.speedr-button').attr('value', "stop me");

    var arr = $('.readable').text().trim().split(/[ ]+/);
    var writeLoop = function(i) {

        if (arr[i]) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.speedr').append("<h4>" + arr[i] + "</h4>"); 
                writeLoop(i + 1);                  
            }, speed);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('h4').remove();
            }, speed-1);//speed for the timout to clear must be 1 less than the original speed
        }
    };
    writeLoop(0);
}

function speedr_stop() {
    clearTimeout(writeLoop); //this does not work - suggestions???
    $('.speedr-button').attr('onclick', "speedr_init("+speed+")");
    $('.speedr-button').attr('value', "start me");
}
```

Here's the codepen link: http://codepen.io/dsm/pen/hHirb

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is twofold: one, you aren't setting writeLoop equal to a timeout, you're setting it equal to a function.  And two, the scope of your writeLoop variable.  It's local to the speedr_init function, but you try and clear it in the speedr_stop function.  Declare `var writeLoop` **outside** of both functions, and change your speedr_init function to *not* say `var writeLoop = function...`, but just `writeLoop = function...`

Comment: I was having fun with this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FAdyn/

Comment: Malk - Very clean coding! I wish my code was that clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the return value of `setTimeout` to clear the timer, i.e. the timer ID. This is a number. So below is the modified code with catching the timer ids and the running state of your app,

```
var timeouts = [];
var isRunning = false;
function speedr_init(speed) {
  if(isRunning){
    speedr_stop();
    return;
  }
  isRunning = true;
    //toggle the button - currently can't get it to stop :(
    $('.speedr-button').attr('value', "stop me");

    var arr = $('.readable').text().trim().split(/[ ]+/);
    var writeLoop = function(i) {

        if (arr[i]) {

            timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() {
                $('.speedr').append("<h4>" + arr[i] + "</h4>"); 
                writeLoop(i + 1);                  
            }, speed));

            timeouts.push(setTimeout(function() {
                $('h4').remove();
            }, speed-1));//speed for the timout to clear must be 1 less than the original speed
        }
    };
    writeLoop(0);
}

function speedr_stop() {
    timeouts.splice(0,timeouts.length).forEach(clearTimeout);
    isRunning = false;
    $('.speedr-button').attr('value', "start me");
}
```

Still one doubt, where does `speed` come from and what should be the value? In your earlier code, it will be undefined and throws script errors too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you aravind. That works! The speed variable comes from the button html.